# Why on 22.04 dash displayed USB memory sticks cannot be opened?

Tags: 22.04

USB memory sticks displayed on 22.04 dash were always Mounted and could always be opened in Files by mouse click.  Only choice now is "Mount" or "Eject".
Can I change to be always mounted?

Now links to created files on desktop will NOT open with mouse click or right click and "Open" selected.  Going to Files is only way to open files or view USB memory files.

22.04 is up to date.

Comment: ERROR - "Mount" choice should be "Unmount"

Answer (score 0):

Question 1410764 from HuguesR dated May 2022 provided an answer to the same problem that I have with terminal input `sudo apt purge wslu` with following output.

```
[sudo] password for derek: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libflashrom1 libftdi1-2 libllvm13
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wslu*
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 1 to remove and 29 not to upgrade.
After this operation, 214 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 196158 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing wslu (3.2.3-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
derek@derek-22:~$
```

Now I can open any desktop icon with a mouse left-click.